# Entity framework, repository layer and Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I'm planning to create a web application using MVC 4 Single page application and I will use database first approach. *And I'm using the default Sql Server LocalDB (with the login/authentication tables).*

Where should I put the edmx file? Under the Model folder? What if I want to have a service layer/repository layer.

BTW, the default template of SPA create two classes for each model, for example `TodoList.cs` and `TodoListDto.cs`. Why and is there any better design to avoid two classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to start by creating a {DataLayer}-Project.

1. Add the EDMX file to your {DataLayer}-Project
2. Add a references (under references) from your main project to your {DataLayer}-Project
3. add `using {DataLayer}-Project;` in every file that makes reference to your Entities

When my project achieves optimum maturity, I change my {DataLayer}-Project into a service.

Comment: I'm using SQL localDb with login/authentication tables. Can I move these tables to localDB of the class library project too?